# Dynamic picture depends on attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

My target is to have a list of file names, and near every item a picture of that file extension will appear next to it.

there is a nice way to do that:

```
p[icon^=".gif"]
{
background: url(images/gif.png) no-repeat center left)
}
```

this checks if the icon attribute of the 'p' element ends with .gif. if it does,
it applies the given style to that element.

but instead of define every file type, i want it to be generic since i have a folder with icons in this format: {file-extansion}.png

in case there is no matching file with the given extansion or there is no file extansion, there will be a default path of "default.png".

There is an option to do that or part of that? if no, what way you advise me doing that?

By the way I am not a css/javascript expert so please given enough details so I can understand your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) for this:

**HTML**

```
<p data-ext=".gif">Text</p>
<p data-ext=".png">Text</p>
<p data-ext=".jpg">Text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("p[data-ext]").each(function() {
    var ext = $(this).data("ext").substring(1);
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/" + ext + ".png)");
});
```

It works so that you add [`data-ext` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) to each `p` (or whatever) tag. jQuery selects all `p` tags which have `data-ext` attribute, then gets attribute value, and changes `background-image` of each element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AEsx4/

Comment: Thanks alot!

it worked very well - I will give each element the right data-ext attribute, and if there is not recognized file extension I will give the attribute value of "default". 

I still wonder if there is a way to detect the file extension by the value of the paragraph text, like the example i gave, or to know if the target file is missing and replace it with the default.

Comment: please let me know if you know if there is a way to do it. as I said I don't really know the capabilities of css or javascript but I want to learn this environment. thanks :)

Comment: The first question is not very clear to me, but regarding 'if the target file is missing', one option is to use `.htaccess` rewrite rules (for Apache) to route requests to non-existing files in "images" folder to "default.png".

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS, you can't dynamically reference attributes in the URL, but you can make them content. Here are some lame workarounds using pure CSS and finally a wishful thinking approach  :(

### Use a class

```
<div class="jpg">
</div>


/* css */
.jpg {
   background: url("/img/jpg.jpg");
}
```

This works great, but you need one class per extension.

### Use an attribute selector

```
<div data-ext="jpg"></div>

div[data-ext=jpg] {
   background: url(/img/jpg.jpg);
}
```

For more on this approach see:
http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

I used `data-ext`, because in HTML you're not really supposed to add random tags, so the HTML creators gave us `data-*` which is valid HTML5 and we can do whatever want with it. Either way, you need to create a new CSS selector for every extension. Not good.

### Closest you can get with pure css

```
<div data-ext="jpg"></div>

div:after {
   content: attr(data-ext);
}
```

You will see the name of the extension next to the div. This almost works, but it's not quite good enough.

More about CSS Functions: http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=130

### What you actually want

```
<div data-ext="jpg"></div>

div:after {
   content: url("/img/jpg." attr(data-ext));
}
```

Sadly this doesn't appear to work at the moment, but boy would it be awesome.

Comment: I wonder if the last feature you mentioned will come eventually.